# how to sync time on a non-domain xp computer with domain controller?

Tags: c#

i have authority to join computer to domain, but i don't know how to programmably sync xp machine with domain by using c#

Can anyone please give a little hint? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would just start a command line process that executes:

```
w32tm /resync
```

Assuming that the computer was previously configured for synchronization.